# CSS only works fine after php execution and reload

Tags: php, html, css

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'villagedb.php';

if(isset($_SESSION['user'])!="")
{
 header("Location: home.html");
}
if(isset($_POST['btn-login']))
{
 $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
 $upass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);
 $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
 $row=mysql_fetch_array($res);
 if($row['password']==md5($upass))
 {
  $_SESSION['user'] = $row['user_id'];
  header("Location: home.html");
 }
 else
 {
  ?>
        <script>alert('wrong details');</script>
        <?php
 }

}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body
{
background-image: url("c413.jpg");
background-size:100% 100%;
font: 13px/20px "Lucida Grande", Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
color: #404040;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
cursor:pointer;
}
.three{
margin: -5px;
width:100%;
  text-align:center;
  top:18.25%;
  position:absolute;

color:#555;
font: 50px "Lucida Grande", Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
text-shadow: 0 -2px black;
text-align: center;



}

.four{
margin: 50px auto;
  width: 550px;
  bottom:0;
  position:absolute;
  right: 70%;
display; none;


}
.one{

overflow: hidden;
position: fixed;
left:80%;
right:0;
height:75px;
bottom:0;
max-width: 400000px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding:0;
color: #555;
font: 13px "Lucida Grande", Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;



}
.one a{
text-decoration:none;
color: #555;
font: 13px "Lucida Grande", Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;

}


.container {


  width: 100%;
  top:28%;
  position:relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.login {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px;
  width: 310px;
}
.login p.submit {
  text-align: right;
}

.login-help {
  margin: 20px 0;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;

}

.login-help a {


  text-decoration: none;
  color: #555;

}

.login-help a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #c9c9c9 !important;
  font-size: 13px;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #ccc;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.login:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -8px;
  right: -8px;
  bottom: -8px;
  left: -8px;
  z-index: -1;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.login h1 {
  margin: -20px -20px 21px;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #555;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px white;
  background: #f3f3f3;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cfcfcf;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, whiteffd, #eef2f5);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, whiteffd, #eef2f5);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, whiteffd, #eef2f5);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, whiteffd, #eef2f5);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px whitesmoke;
  box-shadow: 0 1px whitesmoke;
}

.login p {
  margin: 20px 0 0;
}

.login p:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.login input[type=text], .login input[type=password] {
  width: 278px;
}

.login p.remember_me {
  float: left;
  line-height: 31px;
}

.login p.remember_me label {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #777;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.login p.remember_me input {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 1px;
  margin-right: 4px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
input {
  font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

input[type=text], input[type=password] {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 34px;
  color: #404040;


  border-radius: 2px;

  -moz-outline-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

input[type=text]:focus, input[type=password]:focus {
  border-color: #7dc9e2;
  outline-color: #dceefc;
  outline-offset: 0;
}

input[type=submit] {
  padding: 0 18px;
  height: 29px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #527881;
  text-shadow: 0 1px #e3f1f1;
  background: #cde5ef;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: #b4ccce #b3c0c8 #9eb9c2;
  border-radius: 16px;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #edf5f8, #cde5ef);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #edf5f8, #cde5ef);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #edf5f8, #cde5ef);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #edf5f8, #cde5ef);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px white, 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px white, 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
input[type=submit]:active {
  background: #cde5ef;
  border-color: #9eb9c2 #b3c0c8 #b4ccce;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
input[type=checkbox],
input[type=radio] {
border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
margin: 0 0.1em 0 0;
padding: 0;
font-size: 16px;
line-height: 1em;
width: 1.25em;
height: 1.25em;
background: #fff;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#ededed), to(#fbfbfb));

-webkit-appearance: none;

-webkit-border-radius: 0.25em;
vertical-align: text-top;
display: inline-block;

}

input[type=radio] {
-webkit-border-radius: 2em; /* Make radios round */
}




</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="four"> <img src="untitled.png" width="100px" height="85px"></div>
<div class="three">
Village
</div>

<div class="container">
<div class="login">
<form method = "post" action="">
<input type="text" name ="email" placeholder="Username or Email"></input><br>
<input type="password" name ="pass" placeholder="Password"></input><br>
<p class="remember_me">
<label>
<label>
<input type="checkbox" name="remember_me" id="remember_me">
Keep me logged in
</label>
</label>
</p>
<p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="submit" value=" Login" name="btn-login"></p>
</form>
</div>
<div class="login-help">
<p> <a href="#/">Forgot your password?</a></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="one">
<a href="a.html">Sign Up</a><font size="1"> | </font><a href="b.html">Terms & Conditions</a> <font size="1"> | </font> <a href="c.html">More info</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The background image in the css is stretch and cover a 25% of the page on load then after php run and reload it works fine.
What could be the problem?

Comment: This is not a PHP question BUT please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: You really shouldn't use [MD5 password hashes](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure) and you really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: It seem css problem. Use `background-size: 100% auto;` or  just`background-size: 100%;`

Comment: Thanks, this problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

change the css as follows

```
body
{
 background-image: url("c413.jpg");
 background-size: cover;
 font: 13px/20px "Lucida Grande", Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
 color: #404040;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 cursor:pointer;
 }
```

there is no issue related to php. you can remove the php tag

Comment: Why should the OP try this? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: BACKGROUND IMAGE DOES NOT COVER WHOLE PAGE ON BROWSER RESIZE WITH cover or 100% PROPERTY – Thank Yoh So Much!!
Solved: To background:cover; add background-attachment:fixed;